# Start command does not work when running bat-file via psexec

Tags: batch-file, psexec

Met same problem:
[using cmd's Start command to run exe. Works locally, but not remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645918/using-cmds-start-command-to-run-exe-works-locally-but-not-remotely)
But solution does not work for me - I use full path to *.exe file

The task is install copy application installer from my computer (Win7, x64) to remote desktop (Win10, x64) with checking the installer version is newer than installed.
So, I have two *.bat, one running from another via psexec.
Part of the first .bat below. Here copy installer to remote

```
NET use x: \\%compname%\%sharefolder% /user:%login% %pass%
xcopy %InstallerFolder%\%InstallerFile% x:\  /s /e /d /y
NET use x: /delete
```

Then run InstallProcess.bat:

```
%InstallerFolder%\PsExec.exe \\%compname% -f -u %login% -p %pass% /c %InstallerFolder%\InstallProcess.bat
```

Also tried PsExec64.exe
All is fine except start command:

```
START "" /WAIT C:\%sharefolder%\%InstallerFile% /DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\"  /sp- ^
/verysilent ^
/suppressmsgboxes ^
/closeapplications ^
/components="..." ^
/tasks="..." ^
/log="%~n0.log"
```

It does not work. Just like without this command. InstallProcess.bat error code = 0.
But if i run InstallProcess.bat locally on %compname% it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: "The task is install copy application installer...". Word "install" is excess. Sorry

Comment: Why are you using `START /WAIT`? You shouldn't need it at all.

Comment: Try using the `/D` option. `START "" /WAIT /D "C:\%sharefolder%\" "%InstallerFile%" .....`

Comment: @Squashman, thanks for answers, but doesnt work anyway.
START "" /WAIT /D ... leads to message: "Invalid key: /sp-".
START "" /D ... - same.
START "" /WAIT /D... - "Could not execute batch command".
And dont understand what you mean in fisrt comment - what should I use instead of START /WAIT

Comment: You do not need the `START` command to execute a program.  Just remove `START /WAIT` from your code and just execute the installer file as is.

Comment: @Squashman, thanks, did not know that..But doesnt help as well

Comment: Telling us it doesn't work doesn't help us help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Where these variables are defined `%sharefolder%\%InstallerFile%`? Are they defined on a remote side?

Comment: @montonero Yes, they are defined in both *.bat. Before executing "start" check this path via echo, result: C:\TestAutoInstall\MyAppInstaller.exe

Comment: Does it create a log file?

Comment: @montonero No, it does not. Try to create simple SomeFile.cmd file on remote desktop with "echo sometext" and use it instead of my code: start /min /wait cmd /c C:\TestAutoInstall\SomeFile.cmd. Did not found this output.
Maybe there is an easier way to meet my requirements - without two .bat files or psexec? So I should try something else

Comment: So far `psexec` is a simplest way to do a remote run. Just in case: `start` is an internal command. of `cmd.exe` you can't run it by its own.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Missing -s. Thanks for help.

```
%InstallerFolder%\PsExec.exe -s \\%%c -f -u %%a -p %%b -c %InstallerFolder%\InstallProcess.bat
```